# How to create a debian distro for a java project using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, debian

I see someone has asked this question before. I would have loved to have seen the answer, but it was removed. At the risk of getting down-voted like that post..., I really need help with this, as I've spent a few days on it already and I'm thoroughly at a loss...

I have a java project that's fairly mature. We're preparing to go from alpha phase into a beta release.  As a part of that, we want to release installable packages with a proper app with an icon, etc.  Creating a (dmg) package for distribution on Mac was extremely easy using the macAppBundle gradle plugin and it works beautifully.  I'm now attempting to address distribution on Linux.  Ideally, the setupbuilder plugin would be the way to go, but there's a bug that's preventing me from creating a .deb or .rpm package.  I submitted the bug to the developer and am currently trying to work around the issue by following [this blog post](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2014/05/29/gradle-create-windows-installers-debian-packages-manage-a-ppa-and-optional-sub-projects/#Building-Debian-Ubuntu-packages-and-uploading-to-a-PPA).

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04.3 vm in VirtualBox on my Mac and I can successfully create a working executable by running `gradle debianPrepareappname`.  But when I try to run `gradle debian` to create the .deb file, the build always fails (currently with this error:).

`Process 'command 'debuild'' finished with non-zero exit value 255`

When I run debuild manually, I see the following:

```
debuild: fatal error at line 679:
found debian/changelog in directory
  /home/username/appname/build/debian/appname
but there's no debian/rules there!  Are you in the source code tree?
```

No rules file is getting created by gradle.  I know that the rules file is basically a makefile... and I'm not very familiar with makefiles in general, let alone creating .deb distros.  I know makefiles do compilations and copy files to places in the system, but I don't know what needs to be done to create a .deb file or where things need to go.  I mean, the necessary components are there and they work:

`appname/build/debian/appname/debian/{bin,lib}`

The `bin` has the working executable and the `lib` has all the necessary jar files.  I just don't know what I need to do in the gradle build script to create the .deb file.  Here's what I've got in the gradle build file (I've omitted the macAppBundle and setupbuilder stuff that's just vestigial in there right now, just to keep it simple):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

defaultTasks "clean", "fatJar", "eclipse"

version = getVersionName()
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.miglayout:miglayout-swing:5.0'
  compile 'com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.3'
  compile 'org.freehep:freehep-graphicsio:2.4'
  compile 'org.freehep:freehep-graphicsio-pdf:2.4'
  compile 'org.freehep:freehep-graphicsio-ps:2.4'
  compile 'org.freehep:freehep-graphicsio-svg:2.4'
  compile 'org.freehep:freehep-graphics2d:2.4'
  compile 'org.swinglabs.swingx:swingx-autocomplete:1.6.5-1'
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java/'
    }
  }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class':'com.placeholder.appname'
  }
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  from {configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}}
  with jar
}

def getVersionName() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

String applicationVersionFull = getVersionName()

task debianClean(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/debian'   
}

tasks.addRule("Pattern: debianPrepare<distribution>") { String taskName ->
  if (taskName.startsWith("debianPrepare")) {
    task(taskName, dependsOn: [installDist, debianClean]){

      String debianDistribution = (taskName - "debianPrepare").toLowerCase()
      String debianApplicationVersionFull = getVersionName()

      doLast {
        copy {
          from rootProject.files("build/install/appname") 
          into rootProject.file("build/debian/appname")
        }

        copy {
          from rootProject.files("gradle/debian/debian") 
          into rootProject.file("build/debian/appname/debian")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

task debian { // depends on debianPrepare*
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir rootProject.file("build/debian/appname")
            commandLine "debuild -i -us -uc -b".split()
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I've read says this is supposed to be really easy with gradle.  The macAppBundle was definitely very easy - it was like 5 lines of code.  I barely had to read anything to figure it out and it creates a dmg that has an executable with an icon and everything.  I just copied & edited the example in the macAppBundle readme.  setupbuilder looked similarly easy, if not for the bug I encountered.  Is there a similar example out there for building .deb packages for java projects that doesn't use setupbuilder?  I've tried a couple other plugins with no success.  I've been googling and I can't find anything straightforward other than the blog post I mentioned.  I eventually would like to apply an icon to the executable and other niceties, but first thing is to just get it to build.  So why does the rules file not get created?  That seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is a "debian" directory with all the related files already present.  If you look at syncany's repo https://github.com/syncany/syncany/tree/74c737d871d21dff5283edaac8c187a42c020b20/gradle/debian/debian on github from the blog post you mentioned, you'll see he has 8 files.

At the end of the day, debuild is just bundling a set of files up into an installer.  They all have to be there to begin with. His scripts don't create any of these files, just modify some such as the changelog.

Comment: The Debian directory is there and gradle is creating a control file and a changelog file, but no rules file? I actually went back to debugging setupbuilder and got a little farther. The "bug" was just me not knowing what was missing. However, now I've got other issues I'm running into. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong. All I want is to create an executable app from a working self-contained jar, with an icon, that is in some distributable format - like the 5 lines of code macAppBundle does. Is this possible?

Comment: Building a .deb isn't going to do that for you.  It just allows you to unpack many files to the correct locations.  Its still up to you to create the startup scripts, file associations, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that that's what gradle is for. It does it for the Mac (I.e. Creates a .app in a .dmg package). In fact, not with setupbuilder, but with the application plugin, I can get gradle to create a shell script to start the Java app, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with setupbuilder or how to put that in a .deb file.

Comment: Well, today I managed to get gradle to create a shell script and put it in a .deb file which, when installed, puts it in the desired location.  *phew*.  However, it's a rather messy process with lots of vestigial files created alongside the .deb file. I'll just ignore them for now and be happy it works...

Comment: @hepcat72 please post whatever you did as an answer. I am having this problem now in 2021. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Willa It's been too long ago for me to remember, but I'll link you to the project. It's open source and public. Maybe you can work it out. https://bitbucket.org/TreeView3Dev/treeview3/src/master/

Comment: @Willa Since your experience is fresh in your mind, I'd be more than happy to accept an answer if you write it out. I know I did the legwork, but that doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Unfortunately your project only gave me ideas to do something different. In short I didn't need to build the image anymore.